# How to Update to Thingspeak 401 Authorization Error

Tags: java, json

Im trying to Update JSON data to Thingspeak channel, but i get 401 error Authorization error. Have sent "writekey" as parameter. Error is

> {"status":"401","error":{"error_code":"error_auth_required","message":"Authorization Required","details":"Please provide proper authentication details."}}

```
`    try {
            List<NameValuePair> nvPairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
            NameValuePair nv5 = new BasicNameValuePair("writeApi_Key",writeApi_Key);
            nvPairList.add(nv5);
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPut put= new HttpPut(urlname);
        URI uri = null;
        try {
            uri = new URIBuilder(put.getURI()).addParameters(nvPairList).build();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        put.setURI(uri);
        put.setHeader("writeApi_Key", writeApi_Key);
        put.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        put.setHeader("charset", "utf-8");
        put.setHeader("Connnection", "keep-alive");
        put.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        System.out.println("Url header of post:::"+put.toString());
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(entryobj.toString());
        put.setEntity(entity);
        System.out.println("Url header of post:::"+put.toString());

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(put);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
          String line = "";
          while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
          }

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (statusCode != 200) {
                System.out.println("connection refused");
            } else if (response.getStatusLine().equals("0")) {

                System.out.println("Update Failed");
            }
            HttpEntity responseentity = response.getEntity();
            String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(responseentity, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(responseString);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {

            cpe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }    `
```

output url is when writeApi_Key and api_key respectively checked outputs are below

> 1. Url header of post:::PUT https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/230391.json?writeApi_Key=UEDXXXXXXXXXXXXX HTTP/1.1
> 2. Url header of post:::PUT https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/230391.json?api_key+=VG2XXXXXXXXXXXXX HTTP/1.1

Kindly looking for some one who can shed throw light.. Thanks you so much..

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that your API key is correct.  Many people who have this problem are using zeros ('0') instead of the letter 'O', and vice-versa. '1' and 'l' can be a problem as well.

Comment: Yes your right selecting "api_key" and "writeapi_key" in different scenarios to be known. Selection was problem now it's fine working as verified by inserting single field in nvValue pair. But when trying to send data in Json Object format is a problem.